# Connection refuse when configure "Docker Host Uri" in jenkins in windows. How can solve it?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have create a Jenkins container in Docker by using `docker run -d -u root --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /root/jenkins_2112:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts`
Then configure the Jenkins.
When create the Docker configure I am getting `Connection refuse error`.
[image]

I have also create a container from image `alpine/socat` using command `docker run -d --restart=always -p 127.0.0.1:2376:2375 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock alpine/socat tcp-listen:2375,fork,reuseaddr unix-connect:/var/run/docker.sock`.
The ip of the socat container is `172.17.0.3`.
I am using windows 10.

How can I solved the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is arise for socat is not connected with Jenkins. So the connection is needed.
We can solve the problem by 2 steps.

**Step 1:**
Connect the Jenkins with socat. For the create the Jenkins container with this command:
`docker run -d --restart=always -u root --name jenkins-new --link socat:socat  -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /root/jenkins_2112:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  jenkins/jenkins:lts`.

**Step 2:**
After create the Jenkins container , set other configuration. Then put the **Docker Host URI** like this : `tcp://socat-container-ip.2375`
where the command of you socat container is :
`docker run -d --restart=always -p 127.0.0.1:2376:2375 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock alpine/socat tcp-listen:2375,fork,reuseaddr unix-connect:/var/run/docker.sock`